# How can I use decimal on React Native and How to sum all row value on Listview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

1.How can I use decimal and Looping on React Native Listview
I need to use decimal #,###.##  (9,000.00) from api for show on Listview

2.How to insert comma for thousands ?

3.How to get sum all value (product_price) ?

I have api like this

---

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "productname": "m1",
            "product_price": "1400.00000", <<<<<<<<<< it's don't have comma

        },
        {
            "productname": "m2",
            "product_price": "60.00000",

        },
        {
            "productname": "m3",
            "product_price": "71400.00000",  <<<<<<<<<< it's don't have comma

        }
    ]
}
```

---

render

---

```
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => 
         <Text>{rowData.product_price}</Text>}  <<< I need to set decimal and comma on format = (1,400.00)
      />

<Text> Total =  {this.state.total}</Text> <<<< I need to show total of sum product_price
```

---

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to insert comma for thousands, this way you don't need to return a comma separated number from your api.

```
{((Math.round(rowData.product_price* 100)/100).toLocaleString())}
```

For the third question, if you have the returned result in your state. you could do it this way.

```
    var totalProductPrice = 0

          resultList.forEach(function(result){
            if (result.product_price){
              totalProductPrice += result.product_price
            }
          })
this.setState({total, totalProductPrice});
```

Hope that helps.

I add a snippet just to demonstrate your comment, check it out it does return 3,000 with comma.

```js
console.log(((Math.round(3000.000000* 100)/100).toLocaleString()))
```

Comment: toLocaleString() not working  . why always me :(

From 3000.000000 it returns 3000 with out comma

Comment: `((Math.round(1.005* 100)/100).toLocaleString())` is giving `1` instead of  `1.01`. will you consider it as right ?

Answer (score 0):

> There are many ways in which you can format the number. Easy way is to install [NPM module for number formatting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format)

```
renderRow(rowData) {
  <NumberFormat value={rowData.product_price} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />
}
```

> For calculating total, you can loop through all the values and calculate the total and save in the state.

Answer (score -1):

```
function round(value, decimals) {

   return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals).toFixed(2);
}
round(1.005, 2); // 1.01
```

If you use `(Math.round(1.005* 100)/100)` then the rounding will convert the number into `1` instead of `1.01`

`number.toLocaleString()` will convert number into comma separated local values.

Thus,

```
renderList() {
  var totalAmount = 0;
  return (
    <View>
      <ListView
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderRow={(rowData) => {
             totalAmount += rowData.product_price;
             return (<Text>{this.round(rowData.product_price).toLocaleString()}</Text>);}}
      />
     <Text>Total = {this.round(totalAmount).toLocaleString()}</Text>
  <View>
  );

}
```

Comment: It will be good if the down-voter can explain the reason for down-voting the answer.